# Register ts module when not in a parent folder

Tags: typescript, configuration, typescript-typings, typescript-2.5

I can't quite figure out was what to write in my `tsconfig.json` to register my *.html module. 
My file structure is as follows, and I want to move `html.d.ts` out of the app folder.

```
root/
├── tsconfig.json
└── src/
    ├── app/
    │   ├── html.d.ts <-- works when placed here
    │   └── test/
    │       ├── test.controller.ts
    │       ├── test.html
    └── typings/
        └── html.d.ts <-- it should be placed here
```

I tried using `paths`, `typeRoots` and `include`, neither worked :(

```
{
    // omitted everything else for brevity
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*.html": [
                "src/typings/"
            ]
        },
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./src/typings"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/app/**/*",
        "src/typings/*"
    ],
}
```

How do I get typescript to register my html module when placed in the typings folder?

**html.d.ts**

```
declare module "*.html" {
    const template: string;
    export default template;
}
```

**usage**

```
import Template from "./template.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
   }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm getting 
> TS2307: Cannot find module './template.html'.

Comment: wherever you are template.html check the file resolution path.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's correct because it works if I move the html.d.ts file into the src folder. No changes made to "./template.html"

Comment: I just noticed that I displayed my file structure incorrectly. I edited my question. tsconfig was moved up one folder.